# snes9x resolution and fullscream setting

Tags: resolution, fullscreen, emulators

When I execute snes9x without parameters, it does inform me a list of possible parameters, such as "-loadsnapshot" or "-playmovie"

However, none of these options tells me the two things I most need to know. And these are resolution setting and full-scream support. I want to execute it in full-scream and into a different resolution than the standard one. Yet, I cannot see any parameter to set these.

So, is there a way to accomplish my goals?

Comment: When I run `snes9x --help` it tells me there is a `-fullscreen` option (this is w/ version 1.62.3). Don't know about setting the resolution.